# tabularize text by aligning a given delimiter

Tags: text, output, tabular

My question is simple, specially to those familiar with Vim's Tabularize plugin. I want to tabularize the output I get from another command in the shell. For instance, given the following command yielding the given output:

```
$ mpc playlist
Metallica - Ride the lightning - The call of Ktulu
Metallica - Master of puppets - Master of puppets
Metallica - Master of puppets - Orion (Instrumental)
Nirvana - Nevermind - Smells like teen spirit
Metallica - ...And justice for all - One
Metallica - ...And justice for all - ...And justice for all
Metallica - Kill'em all - Seek and destroy
Metallica - Metallica - Wherever I may roam
Metallica - Metallica - The god that failed
```

What I need is a command that I can pipe this output to, and get the following

```
$ mpc playlist | tabularize --delimiter=" - "
Metallica - Ride the lightning     - The call of Ktulu
Metallica - Master of puppets      - Master of puppets
Metallica - Master of puppets      - Orion (Instrumental)
Nirvana   - Nevermind              - Smells like teen spirit
Metallica - ...And justice for all - One
Metallica - ...And justice for all - ...And justice for all
Metallica - Kill'em all            - Seek and destroy
Metallica - Metallica              - Wherever I may roam
Metallica - Metallica              - The god that failed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is `column`.

Try `mpc playlist | column -t -s '-' -o '-'`.

Sadly, this won't work if you have `'-'` characters in the input, and specifying `' - '` will columnise by spaces as well, not by the entire string.

Answer (score -1):

** Match one-or-more of any sign: '.*' (greedy till second hyphen)
** Start of wanted pattern: '\zs' (Vim syntax)
** Pattern to match: ' -'

```
 
:%Tab /.*\zs -/
```